# iPad app crashes with exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have an iPad app for Rich Text editing...

It Contains an `UITableView`. I have created `EditorView` which inherits `UITableViewCell`.

In that `EditorView`, I add either `UITextView` or `ImageView` or `TableView`.

The app crashes sometime with the following message;

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ImageView layout]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x1886f650'

First throw call stack:

ARRAY : (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x30374e9b <redacted> + 154
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3ab296c7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x303787b7 <redacted> + 202
3   CoreFoundation                      0x303770af <redacted> + 706
4   CoreFoundation                      0x302c5dc8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5   ZohoWriter                          0x000a916f -[EditorView layoutSubviews] + 1642
6   UIKit                               0x32af9353 <redacted> + 346
7   QuartzCore                          0x3277f943 <redacted> + 142
8   QuartzCore                          0x3277b167 <redacted> + 350
9   QuartzCore                          0x3277aff9 <redacted> + 16
10  QuartzCore                          0x3277aa0d <redacted> + 228
11  QuartzCore                          0x3277a81f <redacted> + 314
12  QuartzCore                          0x3277454d <redacted> + 56
13  CoreFoundation                      0x3033ff69 <redacted> + 20
14  CoreFoundation                      0x3033d8f7 <redacted> + 286
15  CoreFoundation                      0x3033dc43 <redacted> + 738
16  CoreFoundation                      0x302a8471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
17  CoreFoundation                      0x302a8253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
18  GraphicsServices                    0x34fbc2eb GSEventRunModal + 138
19  UIKit                               0x32b5d845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
20  ZohoWriter                          0x0008d271 main + 116
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x3b022ab7 <redacted> + 2
)
```

My code is:

```
EditorView :

@interface EditorView : UITableViewCell
{
     NSString *mViewType;

     NSDictionary *mMargin;
}


@implementation EditorView

 - (id)initWithMargin:(NSDictionary *)margin withViewType:(NSString *)type withIndexPath:(NSArray *)indexPath
 {
      self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"EDITOR_VIEW_ID"];
      if (self) {
          mUtils = [Utilities instance];
          mMargin = margin;
          _indexPath = indexPath;

          self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
          self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
          mViewType = type;


          [self.contentView addSubview:/*  Here I'll add either Textview or Imageview or TableView*/];

          [self.contentView sizeToFit];

       }
       return self;
 }

 - (NSString *)viewType
 {
     return mViewType;
 }

 - (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect bounds = self.contentView.frame;

    bounds.origin.x = [[mMargin objectForKey:@"left"] integerValue];
    if ([[_indexPath objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] == 1) {
        bounds.origin.y = [[mMargin objectForKey:@"top"] integerValue];
        bounds.size.height -= bounds.origin.y;
    }
    bounds.size.width -= bounds.origin.x+[[mMargin objectForKey:@"right"] integerValue];
    self.contentView.frame = bounds;

    UIView *contentView = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([mUtils is_iOS7]) {
         contentView = [contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    UIView *subView = [contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([mViewType isEqualToString:VIEW_TYPE_TEXT_VIEW]) {
        subView.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
    } else if ([mViewType isEqualToString:VIEW_TYPE_TABLE_VIEW]) {
        bounds.origin = CGPointZero;
        subView.frame = bounds;
        [((TableView *)subView).layout invalidateLayout];
    }
 }

 @end
```

Comment: Did you read the error message carefully?
`reason: '-[ImageView layout]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x1886f650`

Comment: @Neeku : Yes, I did. What does it mean? I'm new to IOS development. It would be helpful If you elaborate the reason for the problem.

Comment: did you check in which line it is crashing??

Comment: @hussainShabbir: It crashes at [super layoutSubviews]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to iOS development, I'll generalize the answer.

You're seeing that particular error for one of two reasons:

1. You've created an object instance and purposefully called a method that you think exists, but it does not. In this case, you can inspect your code and find out, in fact, if that method does or does not exist. This could happen, for example, if you meant to subclass UIView in your ImageView but did not.
2. You've created an object instance and purposefully called a method that you know exists, and you've confirmed it exists, but you're getting this damned error message anyway. Most often it is caused by a zombie object; that is, at some point your object was dealloc'd but your pointer to the object is still out there being used. You can use the profiler to find these.

To elaborate further, we'll need to see ImageView - which appears to be a custom class. But before that, you may want to debug and find out what the value of ImageView is at runtime, or run the app through the profiler and make sure there are no zombies.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you are calling [ImageView layout] but there isn't layout method declared in this class(ImageView). You have to declare layout method in ImageView class or you have to remove that call.

Answer (score 0):

The specific issue is in this line:

```
[((TableView *)subView).layout invalidateLayout];
```

You are casting `subView` to `TableView`, but it is actually an `ImageView`.  My guess is that `mViewType` does not return the value you are expecting.